# In how many ways does a vector determina a hyperplane?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

The perpendicular hyperplane is the *standard* way.

The gradient of a differentiable function $f: \Bbb R^{n+1} \rightarrow \Bbb R$ gives another idea. Select one direction to be the height $h$. Then, given a vector $v$, take the hyperplane whose inclination of all the other directions against the height is given by $v$.

Are there other (describable) ways?

Comment: [Hodge dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual#Dimensionalities_and_algebra)

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Hodge dual is the name of what I meant by the perpendicular hyperplane "standard" way